# Looking for the better way to make a kind of PDF reader w/ iOS 3+

Tags: pdf, uiwebview, ios, fullscreen, quartz-2d

I'm trying to make an iPhone application which can read PDFs in full screen and follow links on PDFs, but I can't find the right way to do it.

First, I tried to use an `UIWebView` to read the PDF file, but it doesn't work exactly as I wanted (I was not able to fix the link problem).

The second solution was to use the Quartz API to read the PDF. I took a look at http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html, but i'm only able to print one page on the screen, and there is no way to jump to next pages.

Can someone help me ? I'm running out ideas :)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Nobody eard about a better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Quartz does not know how to change pages, click on links, etc. It only "draws" the PDF page you want - you will have to do all gestures by yourself (or use UIScrollView and such).

BTW, I guess your question is duplicated. Take a look at: [Fast and Lean PDF Viewer for iPhone / iPad / iOs - tips and hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints)